# Proofs of reduction of any hard problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, polynomial-time, polynomial-time-reductions

**Approach:1**  To prove any unknown problem $B$ is **NPH** then take any known **NPH** problem $A$ (e.g. $3$-sat) which reduces to $R$ in polynomial time. If I take any instance example $I_1$ of $A$, then prepare another instance example
$I_2$ of $B$, and if $I_2$ can be solved in polynomial time then $I_1$ can be solved in polynomial time, then we say
$$A\leq_m B.$$

**Approach:2** Define the function $f\colon \Sigma^*\to \Sigma^*$ as
$$ f(x) := \begin{cases} 1,&  
\text{if}\ w\in A,\\0,&\text{if}\ w\not\in A.\end{cases} $$
Thus, $f$ is a
computable function. Also, $w \in A$ if and only if $f(w) = 1,$ which is true if and only
if $f(w)\in B.$ Hence, $A\leq_m B.$

My question is:

> Are both approaches are right for reduction? What is the difference between them? According to me, **Approach:1** is uses for hard problems, and **Approach:2** uses for decidable problem.
>
> I am struggling to understand difference between these.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144456/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4266847/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I don't see how you got from $f(w) = 1 \iff f(w) \in B$ unless you assume $1 \in B$ and $0 \notin B$? You also assume there is a computable way to determine whether $x \in A$. What if A is the set of Turing machines which halt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first "approach" is the definition of a polynomial time many-one reduction. This is the type of reductions used for defining NP-hardness: a problem $B$ is NP-hard if for every problem $A$ in NP, there is a polytime many-one reduction from $A$ to $B$.

The second "approach" is the definition of a computable many-one reduction, which is used to define hard problems for the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).

There are many other notions of reductions that appear in computability theory and complexity theory. The most common are oracle reductions, logspace reductions, and $\mathsf{AC^0}$ reductions.

In fact, there are two orthogonal dimensions here: one is whether the reduction is many-one or oracle, and the other is whether there are any bounds on the complexity of the reduction: computable, polytime, logspace, or $\mathsf{AC^0}$. A third orthogonal dimension is randomization: sometimes we allow our reductions to be randomized.

The notation $\leq_m$ is usually used in contexts in which it has a clear meaning. If you are discussing both computable many-one reductions and polytime many-one reductions, you need to use two different symbols, to prevent confusion.

---

Why do we need so many different types of reductions? In order to properly define completeness, we need the reduction to be *weak* enough, to prevent the concept from trivializing. For example, all non-trivial problems in NP are NP-hard with respect to *computable* many-one reductions; in order to obtain a non-trivial concept of NP-hardness, we need to make the reductions weaker than NP.

On the other hand, if the reduction is too weak, then we might have no hard problems, or only few hard problems. Many NP-hard problems are actually hard with respect to reductions weaker than polytime, so it's not immediately clear that the "correct" definition of NP-hardness is with respect to many-one reductions.

A separate issue is whether we should use many-one reductions or oracle reductions. If we used oracle reductions, we couldn't distinguish NP from coNP, for example. Nevertheless, in some cases we are only able to prove that certain problems are NP-hard with respect to oracle reductions (usually known as Turing reductions in this context), which is better than nothing.

---

Which reduction should we "use"? If you want to prove that a language is NP-hard, you should use a polytime many-one reduction, since this is the most general type of reduction for which the proof scheme mentioned in your post works. In other settings you should use other types of reductions, depending on the setting.

Comment: but computable reduction is also polynomial reduction!!

Comment: No. It's exactly the opposite. A polytime reduction is a computable reduction.

Comment: when we use which reduction?

Comment: That's in my answer.

Comment: It's like asking, when do we use polynomial time algorithms, and when do we use exponential time algorithms. It's up to you.

Comment: If you want to prove NP-hardness, you need to use polytime many-one reductions. If you want to prove $\Sigma_1$-hardness, it suffices to use computable many-one reductions.

Comment: $\sum$- hardness meaning?

Comment: It's the first level of the arithmetical hierarchy.

Comment: I seem "easy" is more appropriate than "weak", you mean  "weak" here is $P$ problem?

Comment: "Weak" is the adjective commonly used in the literature.

Comment: give one example of "arithmetical hierarchy" Where we  could use computable many-one reductions.

Comment: Computable many-one reductions are used to define completeness for levels of the arithmetical hierarchy. They play the same role there as polytime many-one reductions play for the polynomial hierarchy (NP and so on).

Comment: arithmetical hierarchy is very difficult to understand in Wikipedia. Could you explain just in one or two lines what is this..

Comment: No. That's completely unrelated to your original post, and also covered in many textbooks and lecture notes.

Comment: we used arbitrarily both reduction . That means we might use both reduction to solve the same problem?

Comment: No. If you use a reduction which is too strong, you won't get the right conclusion. For example, you cannot prove NP-hardness using a reduction which doesn't run in polynomial time.